# Getting "please log in via your web browser and then try again." message when trying to send gmail from my kubernetes application

Tags: node.js, security, kubernetes, gmail

I have a node.js application that sends out gmail notifications for certain events.  We recently switched from being directly hosted on DO to a Kubernetes cluster.  After we switched, we started getting invalid login exceptions in the Node.js app and critical security alerts from Google.  After researching the issue, we turned the "Less secure app access" setting on.  Now, we are getting the error message that says "Please log in via your web browser and then try again."

I'm not sure where to go from here since I can't log in with a web browser from my Kubernetes cluster.

My code looks like this.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(config.email);
...
req.app.locals.mailer.sendMail({
    from: 'myaddress@gmail.com',
    to: emails,
    subject: subject + " " + serverName,
    text: message,
});
```

Note that the code was working before the move to kubernetes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have 2FA turned on for the sending account? If so, you need to make an app password instead.

Comment: No.  We aren't using 2FA.

Comment: You should really specify which node.js library you're using, and maybe add a code sample

Comment: Possibly you need to accept a privacy policy change or similar? I would do what it says and use a browser to log in as the user you are using.

Comment: @samhain1138 - I have updated my post with my code

Comment: @coderanger - I'm not sure how to do that.  I assume I have to open the browser from the server my app is running on to tell Google that this IP address is okay.  The issue is that my app is running within a pod on a Kubernetes cluster.  I didn't think it was possible to launch a browser session from within a pod.

Comment: BTW, I have logged in as the account user from my machine.

Comment: If it was something like a policy or terms agreement, it wouldn't need to be from the same machine. It would just be logging in in general.

Comment: @coderanger - It's fixed!  The stacktrace in my log files contained a URL.  I copy and pasted it into the browser on my local machine and was able to confirm it.  How do I give you credit for this since the answer was in the comments section?

Comment: @coderanger - Well, I thought this was fixed.  For some strange reason, the fix only seems to last for about 30 minutes.  Then, Google starts blocking again.

Comment: What was the message you had to acknowledge? Did it say something like “I’m not a spammer”.

Comment: When I followed the link in the stacktrace, it took me to my google account settings page.  There were no actual prompts.  After that, I went to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and clicked through the prompt.  It told me to log in from my device again.  So, I triggered another email from my site.  It worked that time.  Then, google started blocking it again after about 30 minutes.

Comment: This is really crazy!  We've been using this gmail account for alerts for over a year.  It's strange that just switching to Kubernetes could cause all this trouble.

Comment: We've pretty much decided to just give up on trying to use gmail and switch over to mailgun or another provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, user did need to log into Google to acknowledge a blocker message.